# exclude text from rectangle using fitz

Tags: python, pdf

in using the following code to detect footer in pdf:

```
doc= fitz.open(pdf_path)
page = doc[8]  # get first page
rect = fitz.Rect(0, 700, 700, 900)  # define your rectangle here
text = page.get_textbox(rect)  # get text from rectangle
clean_text = ' '.join(text.split())

print(clean_text)
```

how can I remove this clean text(=footer) from the pdf ? I tried to:

```
   doc= fitz.open(pdf_path)
   for page in doc:
     rect = fitz.Rect(0, 750, 750, 900)  
     text = page.get_textbox(rect)  
     footer = ' '.join(text.split())
     annot = page.add_redact_annot(rect)
     page.apply_redactions()
    doc.save("new.pdf", garbage=3, deflate=True))
```

but it didn't worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tag your question with whatever language your code is in, and provide more information (e.g. a link) to whatever fitz is. There may be a tag for it as well if it's popular.